# How to use 2 datasource in single connection

Tags: c#, sqlite

How to use two data bases in single data source using C# connection connection.

Example

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO testDBNew.module(name) 
                 SELECT (Name) FROM TestDB.Module;
```

Please provide solution for above requirement.

thanks in advance.

What I have tried:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO testDBNew.module(name)
                 SELECT (Name) FROM TestDB.Module;
```

I have tried to use above query to access two databases, but not able to access it.

Comment: What DB engine are you using? it's kind of important. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54644261/edit) and add it as a tag (remember that question titles shouldn't include tags).

Comment: SQLite database engine.

Comment: You have to tell sqlite about the second database with `ATTACH`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html